# Slide in UIScrollView similar to ios home screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have `UIScrollView` . I add images as subviews to it . The question is how to make slide similar as iOS home screen. Maybe it can be done with calculating end point of the scroll, and if it's x position is bigger than a half of scrollView width ,then do `UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:` method. Any idea ?

Comment: Set `pagingEnabled` on the `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Scrollview:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960.0f, 480.0f); // customize it
```

and

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pagecontrol.currentPage = page;
}
```

PageControl value changed selector:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pagecontrol.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

more info: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/